# How do I implement native FB login in a hybrid Phonegap app?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova

I've been searching and trying things for a few days
I'm making an app with Phonegap for both Android and IOS. The app will have both a facebook login and a normal registration.
Using OpenFB I can do everything I wanted except logging in with the facebook app.
Basically I want to know how I can, in both Android and IOS, use the facebook app (if it's available) to sign my user in without him having to write his user and password. Skip that step and ask the permissions right away, sign him in right away.
Literally all I need is to have my user login and get his name, picture and email; without him having to write his credentials (if he is logged in to the facebook app).

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen lately it doesn't seem possible, but I might be wrong. Phonegap and it's plugins are old, some do some things, others don't even seem to work anymore. Not sure if there is a way to do it now with Phonegap. OpenFB works well but it doesn't login automatically the first time, although after you log in you can save the token so you don't have to write your email and password again. Try it, that might be the best you can do. Uncomment the following line:
openFB.init({appId: YOUR_APP_ID, tokenStore: window.localStorage});`